# Adding subttiles to Plotly Dash video player in Python

Tags: python, plotly-dash, video-player

I am trying to add subtitles to my Plotly Dash video player, i.e. VTT captions overlay, in Python. I cannot find any examples or instruction on this.

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output, State
import dash_player
```

And in a html Div somewhere:

```
dash_player.DashPlayer(
                    id='vid1',
                    controls = True,
                    url = "http://86.47.173.33:1935/playlist.m3u8",
                    width='100%',
                    style={'margin-top':'20px','margin-bottom':'20px'},
                    playing= True,
                    muted= True
                )
```

The DashPlayer object has no methods to handle a subtitle track in the documentation. Perhaps this is something that could be handled in CSS?

To find some React player examples.

Comment: `CSS` can only move some text in correct place but it can't replace it to new text based on timestamp. You would need JavaScript for this. Maybe it would be simpler to use some external JS library to play video with subtitles.

Comment: other solution: first use external tool to combine text with video - to have all text directly in video frames. ie. [How to Add Subtitles to a Video File Using FFmpeg - Bannerbear](https://www.bannerbear.com/blog/how-to-add-subtitles-to-a-video-file-using-ffmpeg/)

Comment: The subtitle burn-in option is not viable. I am building an editor that will display VTT  captions from a ASR speech recognition model. The editor will allow the user to make corrections to the text and/or timings and see the result. The final rendered subtitle will be in the EBU STL format and will not be embedded in the video. At transmission playout, a schedule will determine if the subtitle is to be played open or closed. I do want to keep the dash player and not to resort to using an alternative. I might have a working solution by using the dash player's current time in a callback. Thanks

Comment: so you will have to write it all in `JavaScript`

Comment: No, I didn't need JS in the end. I have managed to 'roll my own' subtitle playback for Dash Player, completely in Python. I will post a follow up answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My strategy in the end was to create a div ('subtitle-container') as a sibling to the DashPlayer in the layout:

```
dash_player.DashPlayer(
    id='vid',
    controls = True,
    url = None,
    style={'margin-top':'20px','margin-bottom':'20px', 'margin-left':'10px'},
    playing= False,
    muted= False
),
html.Div(
    id='subtitle-container',
    children=[html.P("subtitle text")],
    style={}
),
```

I implemented my own logic to display the subtitles, in the subtitle-container using the DashPlayer's 'current-time' callback.

```
 @app.callback([Output('subtitle-container','children'),Output('subtitle-container', 'style')],
              [Input('vid', 'currentTime')])
def update_subtitles(current_time):

    subtitle_text = get_subtitle_for_time(current_time)

    # Determine whether subtitles are being displayed
    subtitles_displayed = bool(subtitle_text)

    # Set the alpha value based on whether subtitles are being displayed
    alpha_value = 0 if not subtitles_displayed else 0.5

    # Update subtitle container style
    subtitle_style={
                'position':'absolute',
                'bottom':'6%',
                'left': '25%',
                'width':'50%',
                'background-color':f'rgba(30,30,30, {alpha_value})',
                'padding':'5px',
                'whiteSpace':'pre-wrap',
                'color':'white',
                'text-align':'center'
                }

    return subtitle_text, subtitle_style
```

This callback returns the relevant caption based on the player's current time, to be displayed in the 'subtitle-container'. I also implement logic to determine the style for the subtitle, semi-transparent dark background when caption present, and no background (alpha = 0), when no caption is present.

To gather all the captions initially, I parse an SRT file, to produce a list of caption items. Each caption item is a list of 3 items, start time, end time, and caption text. e.g

```
[1185.65, 1193.74, "You're the one who was frowning.\nFrisco. San Francisco. Exactly.'].
```

The timings have been converted from the original SRT timestamps.

Getting the appropriate cue for the player's current time is simply a matter of:

```
def get_subtitle_for_time(current_time):
    for caption in captions:
        if current_time <= caption[1]:
            if current_time >= caption[0]:
                return caption[2]
            return ''
```

[image: subtitle container overlayed of DashPlayer]

Comment: good job. now you can mark you answer as accepted, and later you can upvote it.